# Angular HttpClient giving error as "Backend returned code undefined,message was: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined "

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a component.ts file as follows.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-candidate-emp-referral',
  templateUrl: './add-candidate-emp-referral.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-candidate-emp-referral.component.css']
})
export class addCandidateComponent implements ngOnInit{
url: 'http://localhost:59055/users1/1';
  posts: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(res => { this.posts.username = res.toString(); console.log(this.posts); console.log('hi'); });
    this.http.get(this.url).retry(3).subscribe(data => { console.log(data); console.log('hi'); }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
      } else {
        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
        // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error},message was: ${err.message} `);
      }
    }
    );
  }
}
```

Now when I am rendering that component I am not able to get the details fetched from api url. But at the same time when i use postman client and send the url request I am getting the response in json.

Answer (score 0):

This could be attributed to several things:

1. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) - you need special care when requesting data from the same server, try using a relative URL if this is the case
2. The server might require authentication, is this the case ?
3. Can you share the output coming from your prints above ?
4. Where is the output in the title coming from ?